# iOS: Show UILocalNotification again after unlock

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, whatsapp, unlock

I need to re-show an `uilocalnotification` again after user unlock his iphone, because the notification is an incoming call. Currently, after user unlock his iphone, the notification is "gone" back to the notification center, and the ringtone is silent as well. User have to manually pull down notification center to see the call notification.

I wonder how Whatsapp deal with situation like this? Whatsapp will re-display the top banner notification again after I unlock my phone.

I searched google and found 2 ways as below:

1. Using `NSTimer` to schedule cancelLocalNotification() and presentLocalNotification() again . I tried this but I got double same notification and `NSTimer` fails to run more than twice, although it was set to repeat.
2. Using `com.apple.springboard.lockstate` to detect when user unlocked their phone . But is it private API that can lead to rejection on app store?

Thanks!